# Android DrawerMenu selected item not showing properly in UI

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make menu item in different color when it is clicked and also persist the color as it was selected from the list. currently it is not showing the green color when an item is selected

**shape_drawer_menu_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/drawer_menu"  android:state_pressed="false" />

    <item android:drawable="@color/drawer_menu_selected_item" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/drawer_menu_selected_item" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/drawer_menu_selected_item" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/drawer_menu_selected_item"  android:state_active="true" />
</selector>
```

**menu_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
<item
            android:id="@+id/nav_featured"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_featured"
            android:title="@string/title_nav_featured"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tour"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_tour"
            android:title="@string/title_nav_tour" />
</group>
</menu>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#1C3553">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_large"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/frame_content"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="end|bottom" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_menu_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/shape_drawer_menu_item"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:background="#2F3847"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**ActivityMain.java** 
**OnCreate() =>**

```
 navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                actionBar.setTitle(item.getTitle().toString());

                //item.setChecked(true);
                navigationView.setCheckedItem(item.getItemId());
                boolean s=item.isEnabled();
                return onItemSelected(item.getItemId());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove group checkable behaviour attribute and put only put checkable = true in your item, it will works. Best of luck!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<group>
        <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_featured"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_featured"
        android:title="@string/title_nav_featured"
        android:checkable="true"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_tour"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_tour"
        android:title="@string/title_nav_tour"
        android:checkable="true" />
 </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: even if I set android:checked="true" to an item, it does not show up in green as it was expected to be.

Comment: You need to change your accentColor for this and use SVG image in your drawable, because selecting issues will helps you above but for color changing you need change your accent color

Comment: from where i can change accentColor?

Comment: in your color.xml
 <color name="colorAccent">#2ab6d9</color>

Comment: have you used svg image ?

Comment: which svg image you are talking about? please elaborate and update your answer.